# ¿Por qué .replace() no admite el argumento que le paso?

Tags: java, str-replace

tengo problemas con el método replace:
en mi programa declaro cierto String y le pido al usuario que ingrese el caracter que sustituirá a "caracter" del stringBuilder, pero, cuando ejecuto se pasma y no entiendo por qué, ¿Tienes alguna idea de que está pasando?, pego mi código, thanks :)

```
public class EjemploStringBuilder {

    private String str= "Usando StringBuilder",ss;
        int s, s2;
    private StringBuilder str2= new StringBuilder(str);
    private static Scanner obdatos,obd;

    public void reemplazar() {
        System.out.println("Ingresa el caracter que ocupará el lugar de \"c\" en la cadena:");
        ss=obd.nextLine();  
        str2.replace("c", "ss");   
        System.out.println("La nueva cadena es:"+ str2 );
    }   
    public void longitud() {
        System.out.println("La longitud de la cadena es:"+ str2.length());
    }
    public void extraer() {
        System.out.println("Ingresa la cantidad de caracteres a leer:");
        s=obdatos.nextInt();
        str2.setLength(s);//realiza la operación sobre el argumento y ese es el nuevo valor para str2
        System.out.println("La cadena es:" + str2);
        }

    public void imprimeConsola() {
        System.out.println("El contenido de la cadena es:"+"******"+ str2+"*****");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     EjemploStringBuilder b= new EjemploStringBuilder();
     obdatos=new Scanner(System.in);
     b.imprimeConsola();
     b.longitud();
     b.extraer();
     b.reemplazar();

    }

}
```

Comment: SE pasma que vendria a hacer? que tira un error? que error tira?

Comment: Muestra esto:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ejercicios.EjemploStringBuilder.reemplazar(EjemploStringBuilder.java:17)
 at ejercicios.EjemploStringBuilder.main(EjemploStringBuilder.java:41)

Comment: Ese error deberia ir en la pregunta.. y ahora te redirecciono a la respuesta a todas esas preguntas con el mismo error

Comment: gracias @gbianchi

Comment: @gbianchi mi pregunta no está duplicada.Los errores que marca me orientan e investigué, pero creo que es más de cómo está escrito el replace

Comment: tu error no es un nullpointerexception?

Comment: ss=obd.nextLine(); seguro es null.. obd no lo usas en ninguna parte de tu codigo, seguro querias poner obddatos.

Comment: No, era este: The method replace(int, int, String) in the type StringBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, String, String), ya estuve checando pero no me queda claro en lo que estoy fallando

Comment: @gibianchi son variables distintas, obDatos y obd

Comment: Antes dijiste otra cosa.. ok. Edita tu pregunta, decinos que error sale, en que linea y la vuelvo a abrir

Comment: igual, obd es null. siempre.. nunca le hiciste un new...

Comment: @gbianchi, tienes razón en eso

Comment: Y el otro error, te lo marca el mismo error. replace necesita recibir 2 enteros y dos cadenas. o 2 enteros y una cadena.. deberias ver la documentacion para saber que es cada uno de esos parametros.

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón

Comment: ok. si tenes algun otro problema, abri una pregunta nueva. Lee porfa [ask]. Deja bien claro cual es el problema, cual es el error, que tratas de hacer con tu codigo y hasta la linea que lo tira si podes.